# Can you call a shell script from an expressjs app?

Tags: node.js, shell, express

Does anyone know if you can call a shell script from an expressjs app?

Im writing an app that I would like to move some files around after a git post-receive hook, but stumped on this part.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yep! Since Express is just node, you can execute any command your server will allow using exec like so:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

function puts(error, stdout, stderr) { sys.puts(stdout) }
exec("ls -la", function(error, stdout, stderr) {
  if (!error) {
    // things worked!
  } else {
    // things failed :(
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Express is just a framework for NodeJS.

NodeJS can run commands by using the [process](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html) object, or the [child_process](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) object.

Comment: But this can be called via expressjs?

Comment: Why do you want to call it from Express when Node handles it natively?

Comment: @jrutter Express is just a framework that runs under NodeJS. If you can do it from NodeJS, you can do it from Express: Express is just another Node module.